# Overloading << operator for printing stack in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void printHelper(ostream& os,stack<int>& s){
    if(s.empty())
        return ;
    int val = s.top();
    s.pop();
    printHelper(s);

    os << val << " ";
    s.push(val);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,stack<int>& s){
    os << "[ ";
    printHelper(os,s);
    os << "]\n";
    return os;
}

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif
    stack<int> s;
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
        s.push(i+1);
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}

// c++ stack -- push pop top size empty
```

I want to know as to why this code is not working, I want to print my stack in the same fashion as in java within square brackets i.e `[ 1 2 3 4 5 ]`. Please help me identify what have i done wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it giving any error? What error to be exact are you getting. Can you paste the error in your question.

Comment: `printHelper` expects 2 arguments and you're passing only `1` when writing : `printHelper(s);`

Comment: @AnoopRana yes it is griving error, could you please elaborate a bit as to how i have passed only 1 argument in `printHelper`.

Comment: See i've explained it in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72766815/12002570) below. A link to a [working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/mXBYval1Ne) is also given.

Comment: next time please post the *exact* compilation line you used. If you had tried to compile it, the compiler would have told you the exact problem.

Comment: If you got a compile error, *THEN YOU SHOULD COPY/PASTE THE ERROR MESSAGE IN YOUR QUESTION!*.  "why this code is not working" is hopelessly vague.  We shouldn't have to "guess" what's wrong (as Aboop Rana successfully did).  In the future, please be sure to include an error message whenever possible!

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, I would keep that in mind from the next time. This mistake wont happen again.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yes, I would keep that in mind from the next time. This mistake wont happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem**(error) is that `printHelper` expects two arguments but you're passing only when when writing:

```
//----------v--->you've passed only 1
printHelper(s);
```

To solve this(the error) just pass the two arguments as shown below:

```
//----------vv--v---------->pass 2 arguments as expected by printHelper
printHelper(os, s);
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/mXBYval1Ne)

Comment: this is more of a comment rather than an answer ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Everything that is relevant to answer a question should be written as an answer. Many times it happens that comments get deleted(by moderator or by authors themselves). So as long as the content answers OP's question it should be written as an answer.